# Background image is not loading up

Tags: css, node.js, express, backend, pug

I have been creating a website for my project using nodejs. I'm using expressjs and have choosen pug to be my template engine of my choice. I created the home page using pure pug, and tried adding the background image to a specific section of my website. However, no matter what I do, the developer tools simply say that it can't find the image(statuscode = 404), even when the image path seems to be exactly correct to me. can anyone please help me out???

Here is my file structure as viewed in vs code.
[File structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/huE3e.png)

Here is dance.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");

const app = express();

app.use("/static", express.static("static"));
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.set("view engine", "pug");
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "render"));

app.get("/", (req,res)=>{
    res.status(200).render("dance");
});

const port = 80;
const hostname = "127.0.0.1"
app.listen(port, hostname, ()=>{
    console.log(`Application is accessible on http://${hostname}:${port}`);
});
```

Here is dance.pug:

```
doctype html
html
    head
        title My dance academy 
        style 
            include ../static/style.css
    body
        div.navbar 
            ul#navigation
                li #[a(href="/") Home]
                li #[a(href="/") Services]
                li #[a(href="/") Our courses]
                li #[a(href="/") Contact us]
                li #[a(href="/") About us]
        div#sectionForimage
            h1 Express your emotions through your moves
            h3 
        div#section2
            p There
        div#section3
            p Our Footer
```

Here is style.css:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Combo&display=swap');/*font-family: 'Combo', cursive;*/
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.navbar ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

.navbar ul li a:hover{
    font-weight: bold;
    /* font-style: italic; */
    color:rgb(0, 216, 249);
}

.navbar ul li{
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 1rem;
    font-size: 1.7rem;
    font-family: 'Combo', cursive;
    margin:10px;
}

#navigation{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: tomato;
}

#sectionForimage{
    /* position: absolute; */
    height: 50vh;
    background-image: url("img.jpg");
}

#section2{
    height:50vh;
    background-color: yellow;
}

#section3{
    height:50vh;
    background-color: red;
}
```

I hope someone can help me out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use root path in style.css like this:

```
#sectionForimage{
    /* position: absolute; */
    height: 50vh;
    background-image: url(/static/img.jpg);
}
```

Note that I did not use quotes or double quotes as they are not needed(unless you have special characters as in [W3](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#value-def-uri))